# Using VB6 to update info in database

Tags: sql-server, vb6

I'm being taught VB6 by a co-worker who gives me assignments every week. I think this time he's overestimated my skills. I'm supposed to find a line in a text file that contains Brand IDs and their respective brand name. Once I find the line, I'm to split it into variables and use that info to create a program that, via an inserted SQL statement, finds the brand, and replaces the "BrandName" in the item description with the "NewBrandname".

Here's what I'm working with

```
Dim ff as integer
ff = freefile
    Open "\\tsclient\c\temp\BrandNames.txt" For Input as #ff
    Do Until EOF(ff)
      Dim fileline as string,linefields() as string
      line input #ff, fileline
      linefields = split(fileline,",")
      brandID = linefields(0)
      BrandName = linefields(1)
      NewBrandName = linefields(2)
```

I want to use the following line in the text file, since It's the brand I'm working with:

```
BrandID =CHEFJ, BrandName=Chef Jay's NewBrandName=Chef Jays
```

That's what 'fileline' is- just don't know how to select just that one line

As for updating the info, here's what I've got:

```
dim rs as ADODB.Recordset, newDesc1 as String
rs = hgSelect("select desc1 from thprod where brandID='CHEFJ'")
do while not rs.eof
  if left(rs!desc1,len(BrandName)) = BrandName then
  dim newDesc1 as string
  newDesc1 = NewBrandname & mid(rs!desc1, len(BrandName)+1)
hgExec "update thprod set desc1=" &  adoquote(NewBrandName) & "+right(desc1,len(BrandName))" where brandId=CHEFJ and desc1 like 'BrandName%'"
end if
rs.movenext
loop
end while
```

How do I put this all together?

Comment: Not sure how that'll help me finish the assignment. But thanks for the input I guess

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you some guidelines;

- Firstly you need to read the Text file, which you are already doing.
- Then, once you get the data, you need to spot the format and SPLIT the data to retrieve only the parts you need.

For example, if the data read from textfile gives you `BrandID=CHEFJ, BrandName=Chef Jay's, NewBrandName=Chef Jays`, you will see that the data are delimited by commas `,`, and the property values are preceded by equal signs. 
Follow [LINK](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/266289) for more info of how to split.

- Once you've split the data, you can easily use them to proceed with your database update. To update your db, first of all you will need to create the connection. Then your query to update using the data you've fetched from the Text file.
- Finally you need to execute your query using ADODB. This [EXAMPLE](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/519538/updateplusstatementplusinplussqlplusandplusvb) can help.
- Do not forget to dispose the objects used, including your connection.

Hope it helps.